# How to design an observer to estimate all states from a single state?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to design a [Luenberger observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer) (or a full state feedback observer) such that with one sensor available I can estimate all the states. A good tutorial is shown [here](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlStateSpace#23).

My system is 4th order:

```
num = [-0.00198 2];
den = [1 0.1201 12.22 0.4201 2];
sys = tf(num,den);
[A, B, C, D] = tf2ss(num,den);
```

First I have a row vector of poles to get my desired response:

```
poles = [-2.6 + 1i*2.39, -2.6 - 1i*2.39, -100, -120];
K = acker(A,B,poles)
rank(obsv(A,C));  % =4
Mo = rank([C;C*A;C*A^2;C*A^3]) % =4
```

I then proceed to calculate the plant poles and thus the poles I want for my observer should be around 3x faster.

```
plant = (A-B*K);
poles_cl = eig(plant)

poles = 3*poles_cl  % THIS IS WRONG
des_poles = (min(real(poles_cl))*3)-(1:4); %This is better

des_poles =

 -361.0000 -362.0000 -363.0000 -364.0000
```

I then proceed to use Ackermann's formula for pole placement using the new poles:

```
% design observer by placing poles of A-LC at des_poles 
L=acker(A',C',poles_des)'
eig_obs = eig(A-L*C) 

L =

   1.0e+09 *

    8.6121
    0.1037
    0.0005
    0.0000

eig_obs =

 -361.0000
 -362.0000
 -363.0000
 -364.0000
```

And finally plot. For the observer (software) to give us all the states as output we need to set `C = eye(4)`:

```
C = eye(4);
mysys=ss(A-L*C,[B L],C,0); %Not sure if this is correct
tf(mysys)
step(mysys)
```

Four outputs can be seen:

[image]

Following this model for a full state feedback observer:

[image]

I am then trying to verify the results on Simulink and am having issue with the block diagram. As can be  seen I have two state space models, one for the real plant and one for the observer.

In the below diagram I am comparing state 1, which results in the second graph depicted below.

[image]

I am using the base workspace generated by the code above:

[image]

Upon running I get an output from the observer which does not track or follow the plant as expected:

**Actual and Observer states when comparing state 4 through summing block:**

[image]

**Actual and Observer states when comparing state 1 through summing block:**

[image]

Any suggestions on why the state I choose to compare via the summing block is effecting the observer estimations would be appreciated.

---

Observer Parameters:

[image]

Plant Parameters:

[image]

1. **Why does the state which I am comparing, effect the observer response?**

Comment: Your system is going unstable.  The first thing to check is that you don't have a `+` where you should have a `-`, or vice-versa.

Comment: @PhilGoddard, thanks for your comment. Are you referring to the Simulink diagram or MATLAB code? As far as I can tell, the summing blocks have the correct signs, and so  do all the equations presented in the code.

Comment: I was referring to the Simulink diagram.  It would also be helpful for you to show the parameters you've entered into the State-space blocks, particularly the observer.  One thing strange about your block diagram is that the outputs of the observer x(1)...x(4) are being multiplied by K(4)..K(1), which at least superficially seems like the wrong order.

Comment: Corrected order of K(4) to K(1) and edited question to add further implementation details and parameters inside state-space blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your closed loop system to determine your observer poles. You want to choose your observer poles faster than your closed loop poles.

Your closed loop A matrix becomes:

```
Ac = (A-B*K);
```

and then your closed loop poles become,

```
poles_cl = eig(Ac);
```

You can try to make your observer poles 3 or even 10 times faster then these poles, otherwise, and set them based on the (real of the) fastest pole:

```
factor = 3;
des_poles = (min(real(poles_cl))*factor)-(1:4);
L = place(A',C',des_poles)';
```

You can play around with the factor, in noisy conditions you may want to use slower poles (i.e. factor lower than 1, since it is based on the fastest pole), to not amplify your noise that much.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to give all details for my implementation and would really like to manage a working solution using state space block. This should be much simpler than the above diagram. Initial conditions are set inside the state space blocks as edited in the question

Comment: +1 Yes, I was not using my closed loop system to determine observer poles, and now step response is indeed different and makes more sense. However, I still think there is an issue with simulink parameters since observer states are still not following plant states. Will update accordingly.

Comment: Try `des_poles = (min(real(poles_cl))*factor)-(1:5);`

Comment: Why are the resulting `des_poles` so different from my above `poles_des = 3*poles_cl`? I get `des_poles =  -361 -362 -363 -364 -365` (which is not SIZE(A) elements since I need 4 poles not 5). I proceeded to edit to `des_poles = (min(real(poles_cl))*factor)-(1:4);`

Comment: Ah right, sorry, it is indeed 4 since your system is 4th order.

Comment: I updated the question to show results from the method you propose. I agree that as you say I was choosing the fast poles incorrectly and I was also not using the closed loop system to determine your observer poles. Those adjustments werte made but still the observer is not working as expected.

Comment: I got much closer to solving but still am having some problems which I outline above. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For which system is it?